# Add pseudo element with Symfony Form

Tags: php, symfony

I have an Entity (let it be User) with text field (let it be "avatar").

Now i want to create Symfony Form Type for editing User Entity, but i do not want to edit "avatar" field as text. Instead, i want a checkbox "".

If user check on "Clear field avatar", when text filed "avatar" will be cleared.

How to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `clear_avatar` field to your form and don't map it to your entity

```
$builder->add('clear_avatar', 'checkbox', array('mapped' => false));
```

Then you can get its value and reset avatar after data bind

```
$form->bind($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $user = $form->getData();
    if ($form->get('clear_avatar')->getData()) {
        $user->clearAvatar();
    }
    ...
}
```

Or you can add listener on `FormEvents::POST_BIND` to do the same thing without controller modification. Something like:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_BIND, array($this, 'onPB'));
..
public function onPB (FormEvent $ev)
{
    $entity = $ev->getData();
    if ($ev->getForm()->get('clear_avatar')->getData()) {
        $entity->clearAvatar();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I think adding FormEvents::POST_BIND is best. Please, show how to do this?